# Image zooming lags on tab change

Tags: javascript, html, css, image-scaling, zooming

I have been working on a web-based image viewer. I am using ViewerJs and this problem is not specific to viewerjs, but any CSS based zoom to image element. I have blocked the browser's native zooming, so I can use the keyboard shortcuts on the image element. So far everything works nice and smooth. Except when I switch to a different tab and then when I come back to it, it lags at first then it is smooth again.

Although the browser's native zoom does not have that problem. And it is only when zooming in it lags, zooming out is smooth. Is there any way to avoid this lag? What causes it in the first place?

For those wondering why I am not using html5 canvas. One of the requirements is that the scaled-down version has little to no aliasing and is not blurry, which is still a work in progress with canvas.

Edit: I've added an example here: https://codepen.io/hiratariq/pen/ZEQovza

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/viewerjs/1.6.1/viewer.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/viewerjs/1.6.1/viewer.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Viewer.js</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/viewer.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Show a viewer dynamically on click a button</h1>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="button">
      Launch the demo
    </button>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/viewerjs/1.6.1/viewer.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
        var image = new Image();

        image.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d2/Saturn_-_High_Resolution%2C_2004.jpg';

        var viewer = new Viewer(image, {
          hidden: function () {
            viewer.destroy();
          },
        });

        // image.click();
        viewer.show();
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Just try to open and notice it done not smoothly zooms in but it gradually gets smoother, then try changing the browser tab and then come back to the codepen tab and zoom in again and notice it is again not smooth. But zooming out is still smooth.

Comment: add codes please.

Comment: Have a look at chrome devtools -> performance tab. It can tell a lot about the performace of your application. Although it can be a bit overwhelming seeing it the first time. Their is a LOT of information.

Comment: https://codepen.io/hiratariq/pen/xxZpOdB This should convey what I am talking about. Just change tab and come back to it and try to zoom in. It won't be smooth at first.

Comment: Updating link to codepen https://codepen.io/hiratariq/pen/ZEQovza